# How to use hidden_field to pass a parameter from new action to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am calling the new action with the following:

```
= link_to 'Add Post', new_post_path(:user => { :user_id => params[:id] })
```

Such that the query string is:

```
?user%5Buser_id%5D=1
```

And putting the following in the form partial:

```
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :user_id
```

But after submitting the form I get an error because the user_id is not being set in the params.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you intending user_id to be the author of the post? If so, don't bother setting a user_id variable. Instead, use `current_user.posts.build(params[:post])` in your `PostsController#create` method.  This will automatically set the user_id on the Post object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the hidden field's value. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag

In your controller:

```
@user_id = params[:user_id]
```

In your view:

```
.field
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, @user_id
```

Comment: After putting the instance variable in the new action, I get 'undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass' for the '= f.hidden_field :user_id, @user_id' line as an error when I do that.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you're passing it as `params[:user][:user_id]`. Try that instead.